# Increase iOS UI-testing speed

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I've been reading tricks to speed up iOS UITesting by increasing the Core Animation speed. What does the following value represent? What are the minimum and maximum values?

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.layer.speed = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `speed` represents the speed of animation on the key (active) window of your app. `1.0` is the default speed.

`speed` is a property of CAMediaTiming, a protocol confirmed to by CALayer, which in this case, is the Core Animation layer of your app's key window. https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427647-speed

`speed` is of type `Float`, a 32-bit floating point number, so the maximum value is [`Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/float/1846834-greatestfinitemagnitude) for most practical uses. The minimum value is [`Float.leastNonzeroMagnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/float/1848569-leastnonzeromagnitude).